# What is the most damaging Wizard spell to a single target?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

What is the most damaging Wizard spell to a single target?

Or well, it can accidently hit others as well but the mainpoint is; if I don't care about cost and I want to do the most damage possible to a single target; what spell should I use?

Comment: The practical application of this question is actually covered by [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67680/whats-the-highest-dps-wizard-rotation-for-a-single-target-fight?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider uncontrolled spells as well, then runed Arcane Torrent with Arcane Dynamo gives 11x the base damage: see the first answer in [What abilities will consume the Arcane Dynamo stacks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70651/what-abilities-will-consume-the-arcane-dynamo-stacks) and its linked spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Disintegrate with Chaos Nexus does 155% damage in a beam, but shoots out little beams for 40% to targets close to you.  The 155% damage effect and the 40% damage effect can hit the same target, which means you are creeping towards 195% damage if you are close.

It's very versatile and I've used it a lot on my hardcore wizard, where you need a lot of defensive spells and thus have to be able to deal with a large amount of circumstances with a small amount of offensive spells.

Comment: Using Disintegrate now - over Arcane Torrent only because it's an instant cast - When I get to the appropriate level I'll try out the Chaos Nexus on it =] Thanks for the tip!